# Can I see a preview of a sub folder in a document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, json-formatting

I have a document library with folders and documents, I am able to implement 'filepreview' or an img in JSON column formatting to see a preview of a file when hovering on the filename, but I would also like to preview the folders, does anyone know how to do this?

I am using `customCardProps` to open the preview and I have tried to use the elmType 'a' on the folders to open the link `$FileRef` but I can't work out how to open the link automatically using the JSON formatting.

Here is the code I have tried to display the document preview which works, but the folder just displays the icon:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "cursor": "pointer"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "customCardProps": {
    "openOnEvent": "hover",
    "directionalHint": "rightCenter",
    "isBeakVisible": true,
    "beakStyle": {
      "backgroundColor": "white"
    },
    "formatter": {
      "elmType": "filepreview",
      "attributes": {
        "src": "=if([$File_x0020_Type]=='','','@thumbnail.large')"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my thought was can I use the `$FileRef` field to automatically open the href to show the content of the subfolder, how can I get it to run without clicking?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, filePreview could only work in file instead of folder.

Answer (score 0):

JSON formatting is limited. There are good reasons. Imagine you browse to a folder containing 100 subfolders. That would trigger an avalanche of requests to retrieve the previews of these 100 subfolders.